# How to insert a variable name into a variable?

Tags: javascript

```html
costOfApples1 = 2
costOfApples2 = 5
costOfApples3 = 9
var howManyApples= prompt("How many packets of apples do you want?")
var costOfApples =
```

I want to determine the costOfApple variable using the howManyApples value. For example, I want the costOfApple to be equal to costOfApple1 if the howManyApples value is 1.

```html
var costOfApples = 'costOfApples' + howManyApples
```

This doesn't work, obviously, but I added it to show where I'm going at.

Comment: You should use a `Map` (or old-school `object`) instead of variables for storing pricing data.

Comment: What should happen if the user says 4 or more? Or zero? Or minus 1? Or a non-numeric value?

Comment: I meant, considering their answers are 3 or less.